# Smooth view adjustment in response to device orientation with Adobe Air Mobile for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air, device-orientation

I am looking for a better way to respond to orientation changes using native AS (non-flex) Air for mobile. The current implementation using `stage.autoOrients = true` is pretty crappy and doesn't look polished the way a native orientation change looks in professional apps.

How are you dealing with orientation change and smooth re-layout on mobile for android (I haven't yet tested on iOS)? Do you live with the automatic re-orientation animation, with its truncated display and the delay before you re-layout your view? Is there a funky workaround that allows you to draw stuff off-screen or in some other way make that user experience feel less broken and more like a native app behaves?

Answer (score 0):

You may set autoOrients to false and listen to [Accelerometer Events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Accelerometer.html).

This way you can guess device orientation and, if needed, perform your own stage rotation with your own transitions and animations.